Питон, как завершить вложенные циклы без exit()
numbers=['']
n=int(input())
for _ in range(n): numbers.append(int(input()))
s=int(input())
for i in reversed(range(1,n+1)):
    for g in range(1,i+1):
        if numbers[i]*numbers[g]==s:
            # Тут надо чтоб циклы прервались. 

Вот код, мне нужно, чтобы при выполнении условия заканчивался вложенный цикл и основной. Как это можно сделать без доп условий или метода exit()?

дубликаты где-то здесь

Вот так
for x in xrange(10):
    for y in xrange(10):
        print x*y
        if x*y > 50:
            break
    else:
        continue  
    break

Если вложенный цикл дошел до конца, то сработает continue для внешнего цикла. Если же был прерван по break, то else не сработает и он дойдет до break внешнего цикла
Точно так же можно повышать уровни вложенности. Вот пример для трех
for x in xrange(10):
    for y in xrange(10):
        for z in xrange(10):
            print x,y,z
            if x*y*z == 30:
                break
        else:
            continue
        break
    else:
        continue
    break


Код конечно правильный, но выглядит это всё ужасно, то ли дело return из функции - просто и понятно )

def f():    
    numbers=['']
    n=int(input())
    for _ in range(n):
    numbers.append(int(input()))
    s=int(input())
    for i in reversed(range(1,n+1)):
        for g in range(1,i+1):
            if numbers[i]*numbers[g]==s:
                # Тут надо чтоб циклы прервались. 
                return 


а без функции вариантов нет?

@user646835 флаг выставьте, во внешнем цикле проверьте

@user646835, Можно через try/except

@user646835 вариантов много, лучший - придумать такой алгоритм, чтобы не нужно было искать выход из трудной ситуации.

@user646835 через return внутри функции - проще всего.

for i, g in ((i, g) for i in reversed(range(1, n + 1)) for g in range(1, i + 1)):
    if numbers[i] * numbers[g] == s:
        break

P.S. Любой каприз за ваши деньги.
P.P.S. В вашем коде обращения за конец списка и первый элемент не обрабатывается. Это я не правил.
P.P.P.S. В питоне такие вещи делаются отдельным генератором, но это с функциями если.

Try/except.
try:
  for i in reversed(range(1,n+1)):
    for g in range(1,i+1):
        if numbers[i]*numbers[g]==s:
            # Тут надо чтоб циклы…
            raise Exception
except Exception:
    pass
#Идём дальше


Вы код-то тестировали? Как минимум двоеточие потеряли после try, да и оператора except я тут не вижу

Любимое развлечение: написать except Exception:, сделать опечатку внутри блока, отлаживаться два часа, прийти на ruSO "у меня не работает".

@BenPuls, спасибо, поправил

@NikolaiVorobiev, очень плохая идея бросать и отлавливать голый Exception (и потом еще игнорировать его). Типичная проблема - сделать опечатку в имени переменной, вылетит NameError, который сабкласс Exception, вы NameError отлавливаете и игнорируете. Голый except еще хуже, чем except Exception, он вообще все исключения будет отлавливать (все что наследуется от BaseException).
