Продолжить внешний цикл при выполнении условия во внутреннем цикле
Вот код:
s=int(input())
matrix=[input().split() for i in range(s)]
print(matrix)
for i in range(s):
    for j in range(s):
        if matrix[i][j]==matrix[i][i]:
            continue

Вопрос: как применить continue к внешнему циклу при выполнении условия?

Заведите флаг - булеву переменную, и выставляйте её после if

Тоже об этом подумал, а нет вариантов попроще?

А что вообще должно делаться в циклах?

Один из дубликатов https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1598821/

А что вообще должно делаться в циклах?
А какая разница? Понятное дело что такого рода код никому не нужен, он не выполняет никаких важных задач, но даже если и нужен его можно легко заменить используя библиотеки или методы. Я просто решаю задачи из курса.

Короче, сделал флаги, работает.

@pythonniy_chainik напишите ответ на свой вопрос

for i in range(s):
    for j in range(s):
        if matrix[i][j]==matrix[i][i]:
            break
    else:
        # мы окажемся здесь, если break не случился
        continue
    # мы окажемся здесь, если break случился
    continue


Форматирование уползло(;

@Dmitry, этот else - часть for. Форматирование никуда не уползало: 4.5. else Clauses on Loops

Не плохо... простите, за это замечание ) я таких конструкций не встречал. И давно такое появилось?

@Dmitry, это старая фича. Но мало кто про неё знает. Мне самому она пригодилась до сих пор два раза.

Да, я нашёл упоминание на енСО в 2013 году ещё. Круто ;)

Хочется отметить, что вариант:
for i in range(s):
    for j in range(s):
        if matrix[i][j]==matrix[i][i]:
            break
    else:
        continue

не сработает, так как при выходе из цикла через break блок else не выполняется. К сожалению, не могу ответить в комментарии, поэтому отмечаю тут.
Далее, вопрос выглядит не до конца раскрытым, ведь чтобы имело смысл делать continue во внешнем цикле for, нужно, чтобы там был какой-то код, типа:
for i in range(s):
    for j in range(s):
        if matrix[i][j]==matrix[i][i]:
            break
    some_method()

Далее - можно даже использовать переменную j после внешнего цикла, так как она сохраняется, единственное - она может быть не проинициализирована, если вдруг цикл по j будет пустым:
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(3):
        if matrix[i][j]==matrix[i][i]:
            break
    if matrix[i][j] == matrix[i][i]:
        continue
    some_method()

Последнее, что хотел отметить - в данном коде всегда будет выполняться условие matrix[i][j]==matrix[i][i] в тривиальном случае - когда j=i, следовательно, каждый цикл по j он будет выходить во внешний, и каждый раз будет выполняться внешнее условие, и вызов some_method() никогда не сработает. Если это учебный код, то кажется, что он не слишком наглядный.

А я свой пример уже поправил. Там всё работает. Хотя код страшный.
